# MSSQL DB - What are the benefits of setting up relationships in db?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, relationship

Im making a C# form that displays some data from my MSSQL server db into some datagridviews and dataflowpanels.

I have not setup any relationships with my tables as i dont know to purpose of them when i can just query on table from my program and use a cell value from column "id" to use in a separate query for a different db.

This is the code io use currently to query for "categorys"

```
  public static void contype1()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            server = "223456789";
            database = "23456789";
            uid = "23456789";
            password = "123456789";
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "Data Source=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);


            if (OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

                Form1.serverconnecttime.Text = now.ToString();
                Form1.serverconnecttime.ForeColor = Color.Green;

                int user;
                user = 0;
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Catergorys", connection);
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
                //sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user);
                sqlDa.Fill(dt);

                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    // your index is in i
                    int row = i;
                }

                // MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
                loadpanel(dt);
            }
            // MessageBox.Show(dt.ToString());
            CloseConnection();

        public static void loadpanel(DataTable dt)
        {



            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                // your index is in i
                int row = i;
                Load_btn_catergory.addtoflowpanel(dt, row);
            }




public static void addtoflowpanel(DataTable dt, int row)
        {
            //clearpanel();
            //MessageBox.Show("aaaaa");
            String Name = dt.Rows[row]["Name"].ToString();
            String Position = dt.Rows[row]["Position"].ToString();
            String Image1 = dt.Rows[row]["Image"].ToString();
            String Catergory_id = dt.Rows[row]["Catergory_id"].ToString();
            i++;
            System.Windows.Forms.Button b = btncreate(Catergory_id, Image1);
            System.Windows.Forms.Label t = lblcreate(Name);
            b.Controls.Add(t);
            b.Controls.SetChildIndex(t, 0);
            Form1.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b);
        }
        public static System.Windows.Forms.Label lblcreate(String Name)
        {
            Label t = new Label();
            t.Location = new Point(31, 4);
            t.Name = "Label_" + (i).ToString();
            t.Text = Name;
            t.Size = new Size(29, 26);
            t.Font = new Font("Minion Pro", 12);
            t.Padding = new Padding(0);
            t.Font = new Font(t.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
            Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(t.Text, t.Font);
            t.Width = size.Width;
            t.Height = size.Height;
            return t;
        }
        public static System.Windows.Forms.Button btncreate(String Catergory_id, String Image1)
        {
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            b.Name = "Panel_Catergory_id_" + Catergory_id + "_" + (i).ToString();
            b.Size = new Size(252, 142);
            b.Font = new Font("Minion Pro", 12);
            b.Padding = new Padding(0);
            try
            {
                string customPath = "C:\\Users\\Aaron\\Downloads\\utopiatechrepairs-9ca9c3728ad38311cb5172f499d3ba56deec9b88\\UtopiaTechRepairs\\UtopiaTechRepairs\\images\\";
                string filename = Image1;
                b.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(customPath, filename));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                try
                {
                    string FULLPATH = Image1;
                    b.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(FULLPATH);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
            return b;
        }
```

[image: Category table]

[image: Brand table]

I was planning on using the "Catergory_id" value to query a different table and the same way except adding something like "Where Catergory_id = Catergory_id" the the query to display only rows that contain that id.

Now my question is. I can do this without setting relationships in the db server. Why would i need to set them up? And after i set them up how will that change the way i query and fill my table and grid?

If you need more or less info please let me know. PS please ignore my spelling errors lol

If i could have some sample code or if you could explain this to me or point me in the right direction that would be appreciated :)

Thanks Heaps!

---

Thanks heaps everyone for your explanations and links! Im starting to understand it a bit more now.

I have another related question. (If i should post this separately let me know)

Q: In this video https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php it talks about some benefits of using normalisation which ive discovered is pretty much the same thing as setting up relationships. I see the benefits mentioned such as to fix/reduce Insertion Anomaly, Updation Anomaly and Deletion Anomaly.

Using the example in the video: What if i wanted to have a record of the students previous teachers? According to the video when the branch teachers name is adjusted it changes all the entry in the student list.

How could i have the best of both worlds where i could keep the old entries in the student table but when new rows are added they use the new data/teachers name?

Thanks again :)

Comment: I think you mean by relationship a primary key using Catergory_id for the key.  The primary key would be used to join two tables in the database.  Using a Primary key is not necessary but will speed up to query because primary keys are hash which would be Log(N) while a non primary key would have N/2.

Comment: Expanding @jdweng primary keys do have clustered indexes that perform fast.

Comment: With no relationships you could have incoherent data `2 - Google - 41` but with no category with id value of 41

Comment: Performance and table size aside, if you use cascading deletes, you'll need them. Also most ORM's need them to establish object relationships.

Comment: without setting up your relations you will have to write tons of code to make sure your data does not get corrupted. For example, you can delete articles without any error, but now lots of invoices suddenly cant find their articles anymore...  Thus your database is corrupt. You can also add non existing articles on an invoice, and so on... To make sure your database does not gets corrupt, you will have to write tons of code, and hope that everyone ever working on your project will use that code. Dont re-invent the wheel, use the referential integrity of the database, make your live easier

Comment: Thank you everyone for the great info :)

Answer (score 1):

Having relationships in the database add constraints to new and existing data. They make sure any updated or inserted row values match on the inserted table and the related table. In your example, it would make sure the Category_id exists in both your tables.

Comment: Thank you. But what if phones are no longer called phones andmore and they are now called pens. 

My understanding is i would change the table row for phones to say pens instead. 
This would in turn reflect in all the current and new entries in devices.
However what if i wanted the old entries in the brand to reflect what the category was called when it was called a "phone".

Comment: Not sure if that makes sense... 
I think it just means instead of updating row 0 phone. I should just create a new row called pens and link all new brands to the new pens id. Would that be correct?

Comment: If you want to preserve the old and add new data then yes, you would create a new row in your first table with Category_id=3, Name=Pen and rest of the data the same as in your first row. Then on table 2 you would create another row linking Samsung to Category_id=3.

Comment: oops meant Apple, not Samsung. I also wanted to add a note, that's just one way of doing it. There are other ways to preserve old data and insert new data.

Answer (score 0):

Q: I can do this without setting relationships in the db server. Why would i need to set them up?

R: Yes, but you have control de

Q: And after i set them up how will that change the way i query and fill my table and grid?

R: Yes, it will be easier

Please, read this texts:

[Why is it important to setup relationships in a database? What are the advantages and disadvantages of using relationships?](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-important-to-setup-relationships-in-a-database-What-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-relationships)

[Why Relationships Are Important](http://etutorials.org/SQL/Database+design+for+mere+mortals/Part+II+The+Design+Process/Chapter+10.+Table+Relationships/Why+Relationships+Are+Important/)

[Database Relationships - Database relationships are the backbone of all relational databases](https://www.lifewire.com/database-relationships-p2-1019758)

[Definition of Database Relation](https://www.lifewire.com/relation-definition-1019260)

[4 Important Roles of Database Management System in Industry - It is needed to maintain strong relationships between data](https://www.educba.com/database-management-system/)